# Custom commands for notation in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I would like to have special notation for covariance and variance and possibly other things. It looks like the standard way to do this is to use `\mathrm{cov}(X,Y)` which outputs $\mathrm{cov}(X, Y)$ (well actually that isn't showing up in the preview but it works in Lyx math mode). Is there a way to make a custom command/macro so that I can just write `\cov (X,Y)`? I have had some success with a similar thing with `argmax` by adding the following to the latex preamble `\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}`. That being said, I don't really understand that, but rather just found it on here somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the LateX code, simply use this (requires `amsmath`), to be added to the preamble (or in a personal `.sty` file):

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\cov}{cov}
```

`cov`  will be typed in the current roman font, with the correct spacing.

Comment: Great thanks, how about one for expectation $\mathbb{E}$? `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}` seems to put a little too much space at the end, though not terrible.

Comment: You can use this (loading package `mathtools`, which is an extension of `amsmath`:
`\providecommand\given{}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\EV[1]{\mathbb{E}}(){}{
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:}
#1}`. The `\given` command is provided for *conditional* probabilities. Using the `\EV*` command (with a star) makes the parentheses adapt to the contents size.